# Проверка продукта по одинаковому id

Tags: java, исключения, методы

Изучаю java для тестировщиков, помогите сообразить, как решить задачу. Есть класс Product, в нем лежит информация о продукте: id, цена, имя. Соответственно, все геттеры и сеттеры. Есть класс ProductRepository, в нем реализованы методы поиск продукта по id и сохранение продуктов. Задача в следующем:  в методе добавления нового товара в репозиторий должна осуществляться проверка на то, что в нём нет уже товара, у которого бы совпадал id с id добавляемого товара. Если же такой уже есть, то должно выкидываться ваше исключение - AlreadyExistsException. Можно ли как-то через метод findById это осуществить?
Вот мой код:

```java
public class ProductRepository {
    private Product[] products = new Product[0];

    public void save(Product product) {

        //{
        // throw new AlreadyExistsException(
        //            "Product with ID " + id + " already exist"
        // );

            //}
        Product[] tmp = new Product[products.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            tmp[i] = products[i];
        }
        tmp[tmp.length - 1] = product;
        products = tmp;

    }

  
    public Product findById (int id) {
        for (Product product : products) {
            if (product.getId () == id) {

                return product;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Product[] getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы реализовал Map<id, Product> и перед добавление проверял бы содержится ли такой id

Comment: В первую очередь в БД должен быть уникальный ключ на это поле. Тогда 100%, кто бы что в коде ни намутил - СУБД встанет на последнем рубеже и всё отсеет.

Comment: Можно ли это сделать как-то через метод findById?

Comment: Можно, но с оговоркой - если в параллельных транзакциях будут добавляться элементы с идентичными id, то проверка через findById и аналогичные не спасет.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема вызвать в `save` первым делом `findById`, если вернет результат, то такой продукт уже есть `if (findByid(product.getId()) != null)` - бросаем исключение. Не ясно в чем именно заключается сложность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно в чем проблема. Возьмите и вызовите в начале метода save метод findById.

```
public class ProductRepository {
        private Product[] products = new Product[0];
    
        public void save(Product product) {
            if (this.findById(product.getId()) != null) {
               throw new AlreadyExistsException(
               "Product with ID " + product.getId() + " already exist");
              
            }    // это имеется в виду? 
            
            Product[] tmp = new Product[products.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                tmp[i] = products[i];
            }
            tmp[tmp.length - 1] = product;
            products = tmp;
            
        }
    
      
        public Product findById (int id) {
            for (Product product : products) {
                if (product.getId () == id) {
    
                    return product;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    
        public Product[] getProducts() {
            return products;
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]